# One of the elements of the array as an object

Tags: json, go, interface

The question is how to get the "from" element? The rest is not a problem

I know that in https://github.com/json-iterator/ it can be done, but I could not figure out how it works there

Json:

```
{
  "ab": 123456789,
  "cd": [
    [
      4,
      1234,
      123456,
      1000000001,
      1234567890,
      "text",
      {
        "from": "123456"
      }
    ],
    [
      4,
      4321,
      654321,
      1000000001,
      9876543210,
      "text",
      {
        "from": "654321"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Golang:

```
type test struct {
    Ab int             `json:"ab"`
    Cd [][]interface{} `json:"cd"`
}
var testvar test
json.Unmarshal(Data, &testvar)
testvar.Cd[0][6]["from"].(string)
```

Error:

```
invalid operation: testvar.Cd[0][6]["from"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)
```

Comment: @Flimzy as? if I have an array of different entities (int/object/string)

Comment: did you want to convert your `json format` to the `struct` data model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple: it is a `map[string]interface{}` hence

```
m, ok := testvar.Cd[0][6].(map[string]interface{})

fmt.Println(m, ok, m["from"])
```

https://play.golang.org/p/XJGs_HsxMfZ